# What does Wordpress do if I save a post without content/title?

Tags: posts, theme-development, hooks, actions

I've created (as part of a theme) a few metaboxes for my post type. The metaboxes allow the user to interact with different instances of tinyMCE. Everything is working as it should, however, I can't for the life of me figure out which hook to use for publishing a post that is missing a title/content.

I've had a look at `/wp-includes/post.php` and was not able to find what I am looking for.

My question is: What happens when I click "Publish" when the post is missing content and a title? I know it gets created and is set as a "Draft" but it doesn't run the `save_post` hook. I'd also like to mention that I've tried using `new_to_draft`.

I've attempted using `draft_post` but I assume that because this is probably "auto-draft" it may not work (I have also tried "auto-draft_post").

```
add_action( 'save_post', array(__CLASS__, 'savePost'));
static public function savePost($post_id) {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since the [solution mentioned here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28021/how-to-publish-a-post-with-empty-title-and-empty-content), WP has been updated and now allows you to manipulate the save process of [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/). If you look at the lines 3035 to 3057 (WP 4.7) the result of the check for empty title and content is stored in `$maybe_empty`. This variable is then run through a filter called `wp_insert_post_empty_content`. If that filter returns something that evaluates to 'true' the save process is halted. So you could have it return false to overrule the check for emptiness:

```
add_filter ('wp_insert_post_empty_content', function() { return false; });
```

**Update**. Note that post information is passed to the filter as well, so you can write a more sophisticated filter, for instance checking for the post type before deciding to return true or false, or impose a maximum length on the title, and so on.

Comment: This answer is much better and more up-to-date than the one provided on the duplicate post.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achieve this by using the `save_post` hook, you do need to add the post tile though as WordPress uses it to create the permalink for the post:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse254636_save_without_content_title', 10, 2 );

function wpse254636_save_without_content_title ( $post_id, $post ){
    //This temporarily removes action to prevent infinite loops
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse254636_save_without_content_title' );

    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type )
        return;

    //Get your custom title
    $post_title = 'your custom title here';

    //UPDATE TITLE
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $post_title,
    ));

    //redo action
    add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse254636_save_without_content_title', 10, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click publish without title of your post. It will get published.This might not help you what you're seeking for.

Comment: Both the content and the title need to be empty when the publish button is clicked. I can, however, confirm that they are not getting published. They have "draft" status after clicking the button.